# 400 Bad Request - Invalid Host on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http-status-codes

I'm using Google Chrome, when I visit this website (bttiantang.com), error below appears. I can't find any solution about this online. Could someone tell me what causes this error message to appear? And how do I fix it.

[image: Img]

Comment: **Warning** - the URL in the question appears to be harmful - "Avast Web Shield has blocked a harmful webpage or file". I have edited the question to break the link so nobody can click on it by mistake.